# Why my archive title isn't showing?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

I' have a strange problem (well, maybe stupid, but I'm too burned out). My archive pages don't show titles when they' are for a taxonomy. This only happens in the archives for a custom taxonomy. The archives for categories, tags and authors work fine.

I'm sure it's something stupid, but right now I just need some fresh eyes to check it out. Here' is my code:

```
<div class="container">


    <div class="pageTitle row">
        
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>
        <?php /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?>
        <div class="posttitle">
            <h1>
                <?php single_cat_title(); ?>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <?php /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>
        <div class="posttitle">
            <h1>Entradas con palabra clave <span class="producertitle"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></span></h1>
        </div>
        <?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
        <div class="posttitle">
            <h1>Entradas con fecha
                <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <?php /* If this is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
        <div class="posttitle">
            <h1>Entradas del mes
                <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
        <div class="posttitle">
            <h1>Entradas del año
                <?php the_time('Y'); ?>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <?php /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?>
        <div class="posttitle">
            <h1>Artículos por <?php the_author(); ?></h1>
        </div>


        <?php
            if ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
        ?>
        <h1>
            <?php post_type_archive_title(); ?>
        </h1>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
        <div class="posttitle">
            <h1>Archivo de Entradas</h1>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        
    </div>
```

**EDIT:** I made a mistake, they never show the title, like I said previously, it's just that *"no posts found"* is shown like an H1 title, so I mistook it for the title. Like I said, too burnt out. For reference, here' is an image that acqua background is where the title should be displayed.

[image]

And here's when there are no posts

[image]

Comment: Is this the full code? You're missing one `</div>` for sure and perhaps an `endif` as well.  You've set a `$post` variable but never used it.  What "title" is being displayed when this code works?

Comment: "My archive pages show the title ONLY IF THEY DON'T HAVE POSTS. However, when there are posts, the title shows up without a problem" This doesn't make any sense. If they show up when there are posts how can it be only showing up if there aren't posts?

Comment: @rudtek see edit, it's not the full code, just the part that involves titles. I'm pretty sure it's related to the page being a taxonomy archive, I believe in the `<?php post_type_archive_title(); ?>`, but not sure why

Comment: @JacobPeattie I made a mistake, correcred it and added additional information

Comment: @Devin Your `is_post_type_archive()` check is _inside_ the `is_author()` check.

Comment: haha what an idiot I am! Please post it as answer so I can approve it